# Controller destroyed during asyncronous call

Tags: angularjs

Given the angular controller below, what happens if `getData()` is called, and while the ajax request is being made, the user navigates to a different route? Does the ajax request continue and is the `$scope`/controller retained in memory? Is the ajax request cancelled and the controller destroyed as normal?

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.getData = function() {
        $http.get('/data/url')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the ajax request will still run. However, since the controller is gone, `$scope.data` either no longer exists or is the new controllers scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All references caught in the closure created by the async callback are retained, as usual.

Thus the ajax callback is not cancelled.

However the [destroyed](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy) scope will not be included in the digest cycle and it's observer's/listener's are removed.

The relevant part of [`$destroy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy) documentation:

> Removes the current scope (and all of its children) from the parent
>   scope. Removal implies that calls to $digest() will no longer
>   propagate to the current scope and its children. Removal also implies
>   that the current scope is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: It makes sense that it's not cancelled and that `$scope` remains in memory due to the closure. This is a memory leak, correct? Since the observers are removed (for example `<input ng-model="data.field">`) that means that the DOM objects would not be leaked, correct?

Comment: Yes it is a leak, although usually there is a timeout so it's temporary. Yes as long as directives are written properly no DOM is leaked.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to consider if I want to add a `$routeChangeStart` listener to cancel any running ajax calls when navigating to another route. Other non-Angular SPA's in the past have caused me some issues with memory leaks, and they aren't always easy to track down.